# Heroku date_select issue Rails 4.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rails-migrations, heroku-postgres

I am having an issue with the `date_select` method in Rails on Heroku.

I am using SQLite in my development environment and PG in my production environment.

I'm creating an invoice application and I would like to show the date the invoice was created. I can get everything working perfectly in development but not on production (Heroku).

Here's what I've done:

```
rails g migration AddDateColumnToInvoices date:date
```

**Invoices Controller**

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:date)
end
```

In my invoices `_form.html.erb`I've listed the following:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :date %><br>
<%= f.date_select :date, prompt: { day: 'Select Day', month: 'Select Month', year: 'Select year' } %>
```

Whenever I try to create a new invoice I keep getting something went wrong but the logs aren't really helping my weary eyes.

Log sample

```
    2016-06-28T17:51:12.801833+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/invoices/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_invoices_new_html_erb__2241545454872084121_70216351109340'
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801833+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801834+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801826+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:   </div>
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801826+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:   <div class="field">
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801827+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <%= f.label :date %><br>
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801828+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <%= f.date_select :date, prompt: { day: 'Select Day', month: 'Select Month', year: 'Select year' } %>
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801829+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:   </div>
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801830+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:   <div class="field">
2016-06-28T17:51:12.778720+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/invoices/new" for IP_ADDRESS at 2016-06-28 17:51:12 +0000
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801830+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:     <%= f.label :name %><br>
2016-06-28T17:51:12.801831+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/invoices/_form.html.erb:22:in `block in _app_views_invoices__form_html_erb___2635260794193137374_70216354097720'
```

I'd also like to point out I've run all necessary migrations etc.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal

```
heroku restart
```

That was all!